# Transforming mysql result array

Tags: php, arrays

I have

```
$query = "SELECT
PrivilageName,
PrivilageExp,
'true' hakkivarmi
FROM users
natural join usermemberships
natural join groupprivileges
natural join `privileges`
where UserID = '2' ";

$result = mysqli_query($link, $query);

$rows = Array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    array_push($rows, $row);
}

print_r($rows);exit;
```

And it prints out

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [PrivilageName] => AddBuilding
            [PrivilageExp] => Bina Ekleme
            [hakkivarmi] => true
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [PrivilageName] => RemoveBuilding
            [PrivilageExp] => Bina Silme
            [hakkivarmi] => true
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [PrivilageName] => EditBuilding
            [PrivilageExp] => Bina Düzenleme
            [hakkivarmi] => true
        )

)
```

And what I want is

```
Array
(
 AddBuilding => true
 RemoveBuilding => true
 EditBuilding => true
)
```

I have tried many different things but no success. How I'll do it?

Answer (score 1):

```
$permissions = array();

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $permissions[$row['PrivilageName']] = true; // You can use $row['hakkivarmi'] but it looks like it's always true based on your code
}

var_dump($permissions);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach($rows as $key => $value){
    $f[$value['PrivilageName']] = $value['hakkivarmi']
}

var_dump($f);
```